# How to create a jpg image with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, graphics, web, jpeg

i'm creating a web application to generate images according to user's input, more precisely a barcode generator. i'm using javascript to process the data input by user. In the end, i want to have my output barcode as an jpg or png. What other tools do i need? I know that javascript cannot create the .jpg or .png file for me. What other tools can help me generate an image file?

Comment: Pretty much any server side language. Are you using php, .net or something else?

Comment: i'm thinking about java or php.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible using Canvas element in HTML5
http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2008/04/saving-canvas-data-to-image-file.html

Comment: obsolete link - not working

Answer (score 0):

I dont know i there any free script is out there but you can try this one:
http://www.java4less.com/barcodesjavascript/barcodesjavascript.php?info=intro

Hope its help,
Karls

Answer (score 0):

I have created previews of user driveways after pavement using PHP GD with a picture submitted by the user.

It's done with PHP so you would POST the data to a PHP script on the server side and create the image from there.

I went as far as having the user click and make a path of the section to remove (the old driveway) and use that to cut out the driveway and replace it with a background layer.

You can set up PHP locally with Apache or IIS. PHP is pretty much standard on all hosting services.

You could build an image editor with it.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php